# Is it bad practice to create a web-component inside another and append it to said other?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

Essentially I have a web component "x" and I dynamically create a form component inside the "x" which will be appended to "x".

I could just do it in the place I create "x", after creating "x", of course.

Basically this:

```
class X extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <slot name="form-component">${this.appendFormComponent()}</slot>
      </div>
      <slot></slot>
    `
  }

  appendFormComponent() {
    const formComponent = document.createElement('input')
    formComponent.slot = "form-component"
    this.append(formComponent)
  }

  // side note, is running this append inside the render function a terrible 
  // idea and where should I do it instead? I mean doing it in the render 
  // function does appear to work...
}
```

Comment: That is what you call, an X-ception.

Comment: Can you create a small snippet instead? or maybe a diagram?

Comment: @IamL I have added example code

Comment: Hmmmm, now I wonder, won't this create an infinite loop?

Comment: @IamL No because I am appending an 'input' tag to my component 'x', not an 'x' to another 'x'. I actually have it functioning as I have shown in the example right now. I'm just not sure if it's a bad thing to be doing.

Comment: Adding it on the render method like this is probably not the best idea, what's the reasoning behind adding this dynamically? perhaps you could do this directly in the render function using the template rather than adding it directly with the native api

Comment: @AlanDávalos unfortunately that doesn't work as I set the onchange event for the input to a function which is also dynamic. I'm calling the function in firstUpdated now instead of render.

Comment: can't you just either 1) catch the input's event and send a custom event on that timing or 2) receive a function in your web component as a property and pass it as the input's event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, this is definitely a terrible idea because you are mixing **imperative** paradigm with **declarative** paradigm. However, if you really need to do this and since you are using **LitElement**, you can nicely abstract the declarative and imperative UI code using appropriate lifecycle methods:

```
class X extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <slot name='form-component'></slot>
      </div>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }

  // Executed only once
  firstUpdated() {
    const formComponent = document.createElement('input');

    formComponent.slot = 'form-component';    
    this.append(formComponent);
  }
}
```

Also, the approach you are attempting is probably problematic. Your problem would be easily solved by render function only:

```
class X extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <slot name='form-component'>
          <!-- Notice the use of INPUT TAG here -->
          <input type='text' />
        </slot>
      </div>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }
}
```

Using something like `firstUpdated` with `document.createElement` should be used to create UI components which have offset elements that break the **UI as Function of State** notion. Such components are date pickers, multi select dropdown, dialog boxes, etc. which directly append DOM elements to the body for managing Z-index and fixed positioning accurately.

Further, as per your comments, if you have a dynamic function which needs to be assigned to the input text, simply create a wrapper function like:

```
class X extends LitElement {

  // Input change event handler
  onChange() {

    // A guard to check presence of dynamic function
    if (this.someDynamicFuction) {
      this.someDynamicFuction();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <slot name='form-component'>
          <!-- Notice the use of INPUT TAG here -->
          <input type='text' @change=${this.onChange} />
        </slot>
      </div>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah wow this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. For some reason I missed it in the lit-element docs.

One question still, though. My input elements are actually webcomponents too and thus it won't always be the same html tag name. In this case should I instead be calling a function inside render which returns one of my components based on a switch?

Comment: Just use standard if-else expressions to dynamically decide and render your components like as mentioned in [lit-html docs](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#ifs-with-if-statements)